# Removing gnome-help

Tags: gnome

I wanted to remove `gnome-help` so i removed `gnome-user-docs` but then the icon of gnome-help is still on my desktop but it doesn't have any document to show and even terminal can detect `gnome-help` is still exist. is there any way to remove it completely? because it's a little annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `gnome-help` command is in the `yelp` package:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=gnome-help&mode=&suite=focal&arch=any

So, you should remove `yelp` and possibly the packages:  `gnome-getting-started-docs ubuntu-docs xorg-docs-core`.

I would also recommend reboot if it is possible.

---

As a general method of how to find the package containing a command or file:

- First, find the full path of the command or file name:

```
$ type gnome-help
gnome-help is hashed (/usr/bin/gnome-help)
```

- Then use `dpkg` to find the package providing this file:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/gnome-help
yelp: /usr/bin/gnome-help
```

Comment: Thank You so much it really worked !!!

Comment: Removing `yelp` is not advisable, since most desktop meta packages depend on it.